# ListSliceContourPlot3D with different number of Contours for each plane

Tags: manipulate, plotting

I am plotting a 4D data (3D space, and time) and I would like to have control over each planes' number of contours. I already set the variables for that but I don't know how to set the contours separately.

```
 g4[x_, y_, z_, t_] := Sin[x] Cos[y] Sin[z] Exp[t];
 data7 = Table[
 Evaluate@N[g4[x, y, z, t]], {x, 0, 10., 1.}, {y, 0, 10., 1.}, {z, 
 0, 10., 1.}, {t, 0, 10., 1.}];
 Manipulate[
 If[planes === {}, planes = {"zy plane"}];
 ListSliceContourPlot3D[data7[[All, All, All, tijk]], 
 planes /. {"zy plane" -> {"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, 
 "zx plane" -> {"YStackedPlanes", {j}}, 
 "xy plane" -> {"ZStackedPlanes", {k}}}, 
 DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}, 
 AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue], 
 Style["z", 13, Blue]}],

 {{planes, "zy plane", 
 Style["Planes of Interest", 14, Black, Bold]}, {"zy plane", 
 "zx plane", "xy plane"}, TogglerBar},


 Grid[{
 {Row[{Control[{{tijk, 1, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style["Time: ", Blue, 12], Style[tijk, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 1, 10, 1}], Spacer[10]}], 
SpanFromLeft},
{Style["  Position                      ", 14, Black, Bold], 
 Style["      # of Contours             ", 14, Black, Bold]},
{Row[{Control[{{i, 0, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style["zy plane: ", Blue, 12], Style[i, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zy plane"]}], Spacer[10], 
  Control[{{counterx, 1, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], Style[counterx, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zy plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}, {

Row[{Control[{{j, 0, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style["zx plane: ", Blue, 12], Style[j, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 0.1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zx plane"]}], Spacer[10], 
  Control[{{countery, 1, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], Style[countery, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zx plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}, {

Row[{Control[{{k, 0, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style["xy plane: ", Blue, 12], Style[i, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 0.1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "xy plane"]}], Spacer[10], 
  Control[{{counterz, 1, 
     Dynamic@Panel[
       Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], Style[counterz, Red, 12]}], 
       ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
    Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "xy plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}}, 
    Dividers -> {False, True, False}],
    ContinuousAction -> False]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not specify different contour sets for different slices if you use a single `ListSliceContourPlot3D`. Instead, you can create a separate `ListSliceContourPlot3D` for each slice with the desired number of contours and combine them using `Show`:

```
Manipulate[Show[If[planes === {}, 
   ListSliceContourPlot3D[data7[[All, All, All, tijk]], 
    "CenterPlanes", ContourStyle -> None, ContourShading -> None, 
     BoundaryStyle -> None, BaseStyle -> White, 
     DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}], 
    ListSliceContourPlot3D[data7[[All, All, All, tijk]], #[[1]], 
      Contours -> #[[2]], DataRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, 10}, {0, 10}}] & /@ 
    (planes /. {("zy plane") -> {{"XStackedPlanes", {i}}, counterx}, 
       "zx plane" -> {{"YStackedPlanes", {j}}, countery}, 
       "xy plane" -> {{"ZStackedPlanes", {k}}, counterz}})],
    AxesLabel -> {Style["x", 13, Blue], Style["y", 13, Blue],  Style["z", 13, Blue]}], 
   {{planes, {"zy plane"}, Style["Planes of Interest", 14, Black, Bold]}, {"zy plane", 
   "zx plane", "xy plane"}, TogglerBar}, 
 Grid[{{Row[{Control[{{tijk, 1, Dynamic@Panel[
           Row[{Style["Time: ", Blue, 12], Style[tijk, Red, 12]}], 
           ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 1, 10, 1}], Spacer[10]}], SpanFromLeft}, 
    {Style["  Position                      ", 14, Black, Bold], 
     Style["      # of Contours             ", 14, Black,  Bold]}, 
    {Row[{Control[{{i, 0, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style["zy plane: ", Blue, 12], 
           Style[i, Red, 12]}], ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 1, 
           Enabled -> Dynamic[MemberQ[planes, "zy plane"]]}], Spacer[10],
       Control[{{counterx, 1, Dynamic@Panel[
           Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], Style[counterx, Red, 12]}], 
           ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
           Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zy plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}, 
    {Row[{Control[{{j, 0, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style["zx plane: ", Blue, 12], 
          Style[j, Red, 12]}], ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 0.1, 
          Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zx plane"]}], Spacer[10], 
      Control[{{countery, 1, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], 
          Style[countery, Red, 12]}], ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
          Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "zx plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}, 
    {Row[{Control[{{k, 0, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style["xy plane: ", Blue, 12], 
          Style[i, Red, 12]}], ImageSize -> {100, 45}]}, 0, 10, 0.1, 
          Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "xy plane"]}], Spacer[10], 
      Control[{{counterz, 1, Dynamic@Panel[Row[{Style[" ", Blue, 12], 
         Style[counterz, Red, 12]}], ImageSize -> {90, 40}]}, 1, 10, 1, 
        Enabled -> MemberQ[planes, "xy plane"]}]}], SpanFromLeft}}, 
  Dividers -> {False, True, False}], ContinuousAction -> False]
```

[image]